# How do I tell Netbeans to use SVN instead of Mercurial?

Tags: svn, netbeans, mercurial

I've been committing files to my SVN repository for months, but suddenly for some reason, the SVN Commit option is grayed out or missing everywhere.
I'm using Netbeans 6.8 and I'd like it to restore the sync'ing with my SVN repository (Unfuddle.com).

1) In the Project window, the blue and green filename highlighting is completely wrong. I think it is based on the Mercurial repository that I once used. But I can't seem to turn off Mercurial.

2) When I go to "Team->Subversion", "Commit" is grayed out. Only "Checkout", "Apply Diff Patch", "Merge To", and "Copy To" are available options.

3) When I right click on the filename in the Project window, I used to get a "Subversion" menu, but that's no longer there.

4) Upgrading to Netbeans 6.9 did not help

Thanks.

Comment: If you go to `Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Versioning -> Subversion -> Manage Connection Settings` does it have the url to your svn repository?

Comment: Yes - the url to my svn repository is still there.

Comment: Does your checkout still have all of its `.svn` folders throughout?

Comment: Could you clarify? I've never checked out files. I've only checked in files. I'm the only developer using the repository right now.

Comment: When you checkin a directory, it should create a hidden folder in that directory called `.svn`. You might need to switch on seeing hidden folders (assuming Windows here) to be able to see them. If these folders have gone missing, then Netbeans won't know where the files are checked in to and their status. Why they would have gone missing is another question altogether.

Comment: Where would I find the .svn folder? I have a Mac, but I can go to a Terminal window and "ls -la" to see hidden folders/files.

Comment: In any of your checked in folders. So go to the root directory of your project and it should have an .svn folder (as should every nested folder under it).

Comment: Thanks - I found the .svn, but there's just a bunch of empty folders and a file called "entries".

Comment: Hm, possibly that's the problem. Try doing a fresh checkout of the project and pointing Netbeans at that, see if the integration works then. If so, compare the .svn folders of each.

Comment: I did "svn cleanup", restarted Netbeans, and everything is back to normal. Thanks for your help, Melv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely caused by missing `.svn` folders. Performing an SVN cleanup should regenerate them. Restart Netbeans afterwards and the problem should be fixed.